# Web-design: "Paging" versus "Dynamic content loading"

Tags: website-design

I apologize for badly formed Title, but I do not know the actual term for the latter case where content loads and expands the page downwards.

This seems to be the trend today, and it is a pain to follow such trend.
I personally prefer paging in ALL cases.
If I have to refresh or revisit a site to find a certain item, I simply can not, because of how the content is loaded on to the pages these days.

Even if a search engine points me to a page where the information exists, I have to crawl through the content to find it.

But with paging, I simply jumped straight on to the page where the information is.

Why do we keep taking steps backwards with design trends? What is the point behind this style? Only reason I could think of is that I don't have to reload the whole page with this "dynamic content loading", but that's it..

Comment: The latter case is called "lazy scroll", "infinite scrolling", "endless scrolling" or "unpagination".

Comment: It is called infinite scrolling and are quite a lot of questions about it from different points of view. http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+infinite+scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on the content. Both have different usages: If you have a sequential flow of content, for example - timeline events - posts on social network sites, in a one after the other manner, you could use what you refer to as "dynamic content loading". Pagination is better where the content of target page is well known for the user, example: telephone number index - When you want to search for 'Tom' you know to look for the 'T' pagination button. Or, when you know to navigate to the 23rd page of a document, clicking on '23' pagination button takes you there.